# Layout panel nopt working with openlayers and jquery

Tags: jquery, openlayers

I'm moving from googlemaps api to openlayers and it is very hard. In my project i'm using currently the panel layout from http://layout.jquery-dev.net/ which works fine. I use it just to resize a panel with a map. The problem is when i migrate to openlayers. The vertical bar gets stucked when dragging. I'm using jquery 1.7.

I test other plugins like jquery-splitter but it happens the same. Please find the following simple example. The vertical bar gets stucked.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this issue initializing the map using the parameter "fallThrough: true"

This parameter is documented here: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.fallThrough

Comment: Thanks! Had the same annoying bug for a while now. This fixed it.